Prove or disprove $C:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|f(x)\leq f(x_0)\}$ is closed

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Given $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, define
$$C:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|f(x)\leq f(x_0)\}.$$
Show that $C$ is closed.

My attempt:
Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $C$ that converges to $x_1$. Then $f(x_n)\leq f(x_0)\quad (1)$.
If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then from (1), let $n\to\infty$, we'll get $f(x_1)\leq f(x_0)\Rightarrow x_1\in C\Rightarrow C$ is closed.
I'm stuck in the case that $f$ is discontinuous. I doubt that the problem is not right if $f$ is not continuous. Could someone help me to continue this path or have better ways to approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

If $f$ is not continuous, this is clearly false. You can basically choose the values in any way you want. For example define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=0$ for $x\in(-1,1)$, and $f(x)=1$ otherwise. Then for $x_0=0$ we have $C=(-1,1)$.

Take $n=2$ and define $f$ as $0$ in the open unit disk and $1$ outside.
Then, if $x_0=(0,0)$, $C$ is the open unit disk, which is not closed.
